# Scan entire network whith YARA rules

Tags: networking, malware, yara

I have a task that I cannot figure out if ti is possible on how to be accomplished and if it is how can it be. First of all I am linux user. I want to scan the entire network using YARA rules from a host computer. My first thought is to use software agents but I cannot find something that suits for that purpose. Is there a way or I am asking wrong question?

Answer (score 1):

Read more about Google GRR:

https://github.com/google/grr

Add ability to hunt for files via yara rules #226

they added it in the last version...